# Selecting iOS-Keyboard when input is created by javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, input, keyboard

When creating an input by javascript, mobile safari does not choose the right keyboard. For `first input` the [decimalPad-keyboard](https://miro.medium.com/max/2826/1*9Gxo0y_J1ey8cljGAeSxgw.png) is shown, but for `second input` only the [numbersAndPunctuation-keyboard](https://miro.medium.com/max/2826/1*OP18XmezhsuFO0OT6ErAeQ.png) is shown.

How can I fix this?

```js
let myInput = document.createElement('input');
myInput.id = 'second';
myInput.type = 'number';
myInput.min = '0';
myInput.step = 'any';
myInput.inputmode = 'decimal';

document.getElementById('here').appendChild(myInput);
```

```html
first input: <input id='first' type='number' min='0' step='any' inputmode='decimal'>

<div id='here'>second input: </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using :

```
myInput.inputmode = 'decimal';
```

use this:

```
myInput.setAttribute('inputmode','decimal');
```

OR

```
myInput.inputMode = 'decimal'; // uppercase M
```

**Explanation**:
In general the "DOM attributes" for html nodes are usually written in *camelCase* if you use **javascript**! Inside the **HTML** you will use the *"alllowercase"* version. "DON'T ASK WHY. ;-)". But it is more recommended to use `setAttribute()` method on nodes because this will always end up in an DOM element attribute no matter what ever you writin'